# Is this a pythonic way to make code usable for both regular functions and async coroutines?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Below is a request handling function. Handling a request means to call either a normal function or a coroutine depending on request type.

Currently I have two very similar code blocks which differ only in the function invocation (regular call or asynchronous await).

```
try:
   # either:
   result = func()
   # or:
   result = await func()
except RequestError:
   # send error reply (few lines of code)
except Exception:
   # send message about unexpected failure (few lines of code)
else:
   # send the result (also few lines of code)
```

Naturally, I started wondering, how could I write the code only once (DRY).

I could write three small helpers (`reply_error`, `reply_failure`, `reply_result`) or one bigger one `reply(result, exception)`. That's an ad-hoc solution and not a big improvement. Maybe even a step back in terms of code readability.

Or I could call also a regular function `func` from an asynchronous task, but the overhead of creating a task without doing anything asynchronous is not justifiable.

However I can run such special case ("degraded") coroutines by myself, here is a proof of concept:

```
async def test():
    # not really asynchronous
    print("hello")
    return 123 

def call_coro(coro):
    try:
        coro.send(None)
    except StopIteration as err:
        return err.args[0]
    raise RuntimeError("not special case coro")

print(call_coro(test()))
```

The result would be (untested):

```
async def handle_request(func, is_async):
    try:
        if is_async:
            result = await func()
        else:
            result = func()
    except ..... # error handling as above
```

and the usage:

```
is_async = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func)
if is_async:
    # create_task == ensure_future in Python < 3.7
    asyncio.create_task(handle_request(func, True))
else:
    call_coro(handle_request(func, False))
```

That is what I have tried so far and what I am considering as a replacement of the current code. Is it Pythonic or is it the opposite?

Comment: You can't, really. Co-routines need to cooperate (which is what `await` does), while regular functions do not. When you don't cooperate and work in a synchronous model instead, the fundamental behaviour changes.

Comment: Do *you* think that sprinkling `if.. else` blocks through your code to try and support both models is Pythonic? If so, then stick to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's just that one `if..else`. Otherwise I would not say the two versions are very similar.

Comment: *Or I could call also a regular function func from an asynchronous task, but the overhead of creating a task without doing anything asynchronous is not justifiable.* Why is it not justifiable? It's certainly much cleaner and simpler. If the function is short, *just run it*. The `asyncio` codebase is full of synchronous callbacks that are executed much like that.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are `await func()` and `func()` versions. If `func()` is an asynchronous task, why is there a synchronous version?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Each request type has its own `func` handler. Some requests have sync, some async. The handler is chosen according to which type of request arrives.

Comment: Why isn't `if .. else` with `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction` Pythonic enough? I think it is really simple and clear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters About "justifiable". Thank you for pointing that out. I was judging only by amount of code uselessly executed.

Comment: @VPfB: Why is there a distinction between request types? Can't you handle all requests asynchronously?

Comment: @MartijnPieters (not sure if I understand your question correctly) It is a RPC server for mainly home automation tasks. The system is modular, each module can expose any of its own functions to be available over RPC. Some operations are real-time. I just want to keep it simple, fast and predictable. That's why the preference for synchronous.

Comment: @VPfB: but now that choice is making your life anything but simple and predictable. You end up having to duplicate your whole API between synchronous and asynchronous modes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is an misunderstanding, I'm afraid. Write any function (sync or async), register it and that's it. Other modules may then call it remotely and receive results.

Comment: @VPfB: You misunderstand my point. *Your* life as a system architect is not simpler. You now have to support two models of execution.